# refresh the main panel screen in shiny using the action button

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app and I want to refresh the main panel screen. Here is a sample code. I have a submit button to display the data and I have a re-fresh button to clear the screen. I am not so sure how to code the re-fresh button in R and shiny since I am new to this.  Thanks for looking into

```
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10),
        actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                   class = "btn btn-primary"),

        actionButton("refresh1" ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"),
                   class = "btn btn-primary")

   ),
   mainPanel(
   # UI output
     uiOutput("dt")
   )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
   observeEvent(input$submit1, {
     lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
       output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
       iris[1:amtTable, ]
       })
     })
   })

  output$dt <- renderUI({
    tagList(lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i))
   }))
 })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add the possibility of return nothing from the `renderUI()` if the refresh button is used.
As it is not that straightforward to reset an action button you would have to use a workaround with a reactive variable.

`if(global$refresh) return()`

This reactive variable you can control with the refresh and submit button
E.g. `if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)`
which you wrap in seperate observe functions.
Full code see below:

```
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10),
      actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                   class = "btn btn-primary"),

      actionButton("refresh1" ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"),
                   class = "btn btn-primary")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      # UI output
      uiOutput("dt")
    )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  global <- reactiveValues(refresh = FALSE)

  observe({
    if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)
  })

  observe({
    if(input$submit1) isolate(global$refresh <- FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
      output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
        iris[1:amtTable, ]
      })
    })
  })

  output$dt <- renderUI({
    if(global$refresh) return()
    tagList(lapply(1:10, function(i) {
      dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i))
    }))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks you're a life saver. One more thing, is there a way also to refresh the select input back to 1 once I hit the refresh button. For now it is refreshing the main panel but the selectinput does not initialize to 1. Appreciate it!

Comment: just add `updateSelectInput(session, "amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10, 1)` after `if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)`

Comment: Sorry one more thing, how do I display a text on the main panel such Amount.Table1, Amount.Table2 etc for each individual tables. It seems the paste0 does not work. Appreciate it!

Comment: you mean like `textOutput()`. However, comments are not supposed to discuss (multiple) addit. questions,...thanks for understanding

Comment: No worries. Thank you  for your time. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I do apologise I am new to this website and to R and shiny. Hope you understand. I am learning a lot from here.