# R Shiny: automatically refreshing a main panel without using a refresh button

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app with multiple `actionButton` commands.  When I click each button individually (e.g., to plot a graph or render a table), I would like my main panel to automatically update/refresh with the corresponding graph or table.  Instead, my Shiny app simply appends the output of one `actionButton` to the previous output of the other `actionButton` within the same panel.

From previous Stack Overflow posts, it seems that the only way around this problem is to implement a refresh button.  For instance, in the following MWE:

```
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10),
      actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                   class = "btn btn-primary"),

      actionButton("refresh1" ,"Refresh", icon("refresh"),
                   class = "btn btn-primary")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      # UI output
      uiOutput("dt")
    )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  global <- reactiveValues(refresh = FALSE)

  observe({
    if(input$refresh1) isolate(global$refresh <- TRUE)
  })

  observe({
    if(input$submit1) isolate(global$refresh <- FALSE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
      output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
        iris[1:amtTable, ]
      })
    })
  })

  output$dt <- renderUI({
    if(global$refresh) return()
    tagList(lapply(1:10, function(i) {
      dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i))
    }))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43522607

You need to click on the refresh button in order to clear the previous output before displaying a new output, otherwise they will stack on top of each other.

Is there a way to dynamically/reactively refresh a main panel without explicitly clicking on a refresh button?  For instance, it would be nice to click on a new `actionButton` button to display the next output and have it auto-refresh the main panel at the same time.  Please feel free to supply your own MWE to show how this process could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks familiar ;)

Turns out you were right with your idea. Basically you have to trigger the output twice. Once to clear the panel and once to write the new outputs. So thats what i do below with `global$dt`.

Full app below:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("amountTable", "Amount Tables", 1:10),
      actionButton("submit1" ,"Submit", icon("refresh"),
                   class = "btn btn-primary")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("dt")
    )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {

  global <- reactiveValues(dt = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(amtTable) {
      output[[paste0('T', amtTable)]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
        iris[1:amtTable, ]
      })
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit1, {
    global$dt <- NULL
    global$dt <- tagList(lapply(1:input$amountTable, function(i) {
      dataTableOutput(paste0('T', i))
    }))
  })

  output$dt <- renderUI({
    global$dt
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: ok wow, I sent you a LinkedIn contact request to make friends :)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: btw, I posted another similar one, if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055272/r-shiny-refreshing-overriding-actionbutton-output

Comment: ah that was you :) Thanks for the request! Feel free to upvote if you like the answer. I took a look at the other question and posted an answer. I somehow found `renderUI()` more useful. So the answers are interestingly not really consistent, even though the questions are quite similar. Probably you could also answer the other two also with `renderUI()`. Anyway, I hope it helps ;)