# Refreshing R Shiny Result Panel without closing app

Tags: r, shiny

I am updating one of my Shiny apps and have implemented a "Refresh" button that is supposed to remove output from the Result Panel (*i.e.*, where plots/tables are printed to) in Shiny:

```
 actionBttn(inputId = "refresh",
            label = "Refresh",
            color = "success",
            style = "jelly",
            size ="sm",
            block = FALSE
           )
```

I have seen this previous SO Post: [refresh the main panel screen in shiny using the action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521202/refresh-the-main-panel-screen-in-shiny-using-the-action-button), which is not exactly what I'm after, since running it simply closes the app itself (which can be accomplished directly in RStudio anyway). I swapped an `observe()` for an `observeEvent()`. Trying it both ways gave the same behaviour.

In my case, the app window should remain open, but upon pressing the "Refresh" button, should result in a blank Result Panel.

Comment: What do you mean by "closes the app itself"?. I can see that the answer makes the render functions return nothing (hence removing the output), but the app doesn't close.

Comment: Thanks. It was  bug in my own code. Implementing the solution found in the linked post works, but instead of producing a blank canvas, the word `NULL` instead appears.